# Is DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMNUMBER a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator?

Tags: oracle

[Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65704) clearly states that `DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES` is a cryptographically secure pseudo-random sequence of bytes.

But how about `DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMNUMBER`? (or `DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMINTEGER`)  Are they cryptographically secure also?  If so, are there any evidences of it? (documentation, source code, ...)

My guess is that `DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMNUMBER` internal implementation is probably based on `DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES`, but I was not able to find this information in the docs.  Even if this is the case, it is not clear, for example, if `DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMNUMBER` generation method is biased or not ([check this article](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html), if you don't have an idea of what I am talking about).

Answer (score 1):

They all use the same ANSI X.931 RNG algorithm as we can see from this doc:
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2570454_1.html

Comment: Oracle being Oracle. Instead of keeping the document publicly available, they keep it closed for subscribers.

Comment: At least you can rely on GOAL text:
>> The purpose of the note is to indicate that Random Number Generator of DBMS_CRYPTO package all use the same ANSI X.931 RNG algorithm.

Comment: Will, that is indeed a relevant information but I feel it is not enough to answer my question. My concern is if the functions are cryptographically secure. I am not an expert in randomness generation, but I would say this is more related with the entropy source than the algorithm used. Also, it is important to note that the algorithm name is X9.31 (not X.931 as the document says).